# "Practice makes perfect" and "c'est en forgeant qu'on devient forgeron"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

Trying to translating "practice makes perfect" (i.e. if one practices an activity enough, one will eventually master it; see https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/practice+makes+perfect) I encountered the expression

> c'est en forgeant qu'on devient forgeron

Is it a colloquial expression? What some other common idiomatic ways to express the same idea in French?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je ne connais pas d'expression plus commune que celle que tu cites pour communiquer les vertus de la pratique et donc de l'expérience.

Elle nous vient des latins en compagnie d'une autre beaucoup plus générale :

*En pratiquant son art on devient artisan.*

qui ne se répandra pas identiquement.
Issue du monde manufacturier (*fabricando fit faber*)(*1), elle parle d'abord en ce monde.
Pour signifier la même chose, le monde agricole avait les siennes qui n'ont cependant pas non plus connu le même succès :

*Expérience, en culture, passe science*

*L'expérience s'achète chèrement, mais c'est la seule école qui puisse instruire les sots*

Dans le même genre d'idées (et toujours sans le même succès) on connaissait aussi :

*Qui beaucoup pratique, beaucoup apprend*

---

<sup>Et pour finir par une rigolade, on citera comment Cavanna l'a utilisée : *"C'est en forgeant qu'on devient forgeron, c'est en limant qu'on devient limaçon, c'est en polissant qu'on devient polisson, c'est en lisant qu'on devient liseron... Mais pour devenir riche, bon Dieu, comment fait-on ?"*</sup>

---

<sup>*1 : On observera que l'étymologie de *forger* remonte au latin *fabricare*.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

« C'est en forgeant qu'on devient forgeron. » is not colloquial at all; it's a well established saying;

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/forger) Proverbe, au fig. C'est en forgeant qu'on devient forgeron. L'habileté vient avec l'expérience. À force de forger on devient forgeron (BREMOND, Hist. sent. relig., t. 3, 1921, p. 73).

L'origine de ce proverbe semble inconnue (première trace au XVième siècle, [l'internaute](http://www.linternaute.com/proverbe/329/c-est-en-forgeant-qu-on-devient-forgeron/)).

Another idea,  close to the mind of this saying and also embodied in an idiomatic expression, a saying in fact, is this one;

- Petit à petit, la goutte creuse la pierre. ([l'internaute](http://www.linternaute.com/proverbe/246/goutte-a-goutte-l-eau-creuse-la-pierre/))

Of the same nature,  the following one can also be quoted;

- Petit à petit, l'oiseau fait son nid.

In those two latter sayings the idea is, in the words founds on the site referred to, that little by little and through infinite repetition, a small action will have an effect, and perseverance will get the better of anything.
(*Peu à peu et par la répétition infinie, une chose minime produit son effet. La persévérance vient à bout de tout.*)
There is stressed in this idea the underlying and understated principle inherent to the French counterpart (C'est en forgeant…) that practice will bring you to a point of perfection, a point where all the difficulties have been overcome, this being so as practice consists also in a great number of repetitions that little by little render the difficulties null, or, in other words, make your aim a reality. More precisely one should say "C'est en forgeant beaucoup/souvent que l'on devient forgeron". However, those two sayings do not stress the idea that it is the actual mingling with the particular thing you are interested in that will bring to you a knowledge of it. This is also implicit in the English saying either : it doesn't say you have to grapple with the thing itself although that is quite implicit.